# I am sending a variable in the function as var, but I am recieving it as val

Tags: scala

This is the first time I am using Scala. I have an object stored in a var. I am sending that var to a function. In the function I need to change some of the properties. But Scala says that I am reassigning to a val.

Here is my code

```
var bookletInfo = new BookletInfo(
   id              = Some(0),
   name            = "",
)

bookletInfo = Convert(bookletInfo)

def Convert(bookletInfo: BookletInfo) = {
   bookletInfo.name = "Booklet"
   bookletInfo.id = Some(1)
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's the definition of `BookletInfo`? If its members are vals (for instance, if it's an immutable case class) you won't be able to reassign them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... So basically when you do something like this:

```
var b: MyObject = new MyObject()
```

there are three things in that statement - `identifier`, `variable` and `value`. So you know... A `variable` of type `MyObject` is created which is identified by `identifier` and the value of `variable` - the `value` which is a new instance of `MyObject`.

Now, the concept of `mutability` applies to both `variable` and the `value` meaning the `vairable` can be `mutable` or `immutable`  independent of "value" being `mutable` or not and vice-verse.

Now you can have,

```
// immutble variable and immutable value
val m1 = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[ String, String ]()

// mutable variable and immutabe value
var m2 = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[ String, String ]()

// immutable variable and mutabe value
val m3 = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[ String, String ]()

// mutable variable and mutabe value
var m4 = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[ String, String ]()
```

As you already know you can not `mutate` ( change ) something which is `immutable`, you can can not `reassign` ( as the value of a variable is its assignment ) an `immutable` `variable` similarly you can not `mutable` an `immutable` `value`.

Now... When it comes to functions... the function argument `variable`s are all `immutable` ( It says nothing about `value` ).

So... basically when you pass some `value` ( regardless of was it referred by a `mutable` or `immutable` `variable` ), the `variable` referring to it inside the function will always be `immutable`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to guess and say that as @Mikesname suggested that BookletInfo is defined in such a way that `id` and `name` are `val`s and thus immutable.  You could change them to `vars`, but a better approach could be something like this:

```
case class BookletInfo(id:Option[Int], name:String) //name could also be an option too

var bookletInfo = BookletInfo(None, "")

bookletInfo = convert(bookletInfo)

def convert(bookletInfo: BookletInfo):BookletInfo = {
  bookletInfo.copy(id = Some(1), name = "Booklet"
}
```

Here we keep `BookletInfo` as an immutable class (a case class), and leverage the `copy()` functionality to produce a new `BookletInfo` from it.

With a functional language like Scala, you should try and design around immutability and avoid side effecting.  Doing so can lead to cleaner and more deterministic code (easier testing too).  Fallback to mutability when the situation will clearly benefit from it (high performance concerns as a possible reason), but start with immutability.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, the arguments of a function are immutable, so if you pass in a var or a val it doesnt matter because a function paraneter us treated as a val.

Try creating a copy of the parameter, edit it and then return it. This should solve your problem.

Comment: With the exception of constructors, I believe this is true.