# How to set value to a property in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a class in Scala which has to properties. I want to set some values to that property. Here is the class

```
class ParticipationStateTransition(fromState: String = Nil, toState: String = Nil) {

}
```

Here is the code where I am setting some property -

```
var change: ParticipationStateTransition = new ParticipationStateTransition
change.fromStatus = ri.partStatus
```

It is giving me an error. It is saying:

> cannot resolve property fromStatus

Comment: Its like, you are treating SO as your personal tutor. Your last 5-6 questions clearly indicate that you have not read anything about Scala. I suggest you stop asking question on SO for now and actually put time in learning Scala. Twitter's Scala School - https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/ is one of the best short Scala resources.

Comment: Also, this time it was a typing mistake that you did. There is no `fromStatus` in your class. Just `fromState` and `toState`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, sorry typing mistake in SO. But if I remove the vars then I get errors

Comment: Yes you will. Becasue by default every class member is a `val` in which created an `immutable` variable, which means you can not mutate it. And the error which you will receive will be `error: reassignment to val` and not `cannot resolve property fromStatus`.

Comment: To get a short explanation about immutability in , you can read this aanswer ->http://stackoverflow.com/a/28795232/1151929

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, I didn't copy paste the code. I wrote the code in SO. I admitted it was a typo but it wasn't a mistake in my actual code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as per the comments, the error is not correctly specified. The question is therefore lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `var` before fromState, like

```
class ParticipationStateTransition(var fromState: String = Nil, var toState: String = Nil) {

}
```

Comment: or make `ParticipationStateTransition` a case class :)

Comment: case class variables are by default, immutable, so you still have to use var, if you want to change the value of variable in java style, other wise use copy method.

Comment: @S_Karthik Agree. It's just that `ParticipationStateTransition` looks like the kind of thing that I would like to be immutable.

Comment: @ kaktusito, I also like to work with immutable style, that makes functional programming really fun to code.